# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint PK. Cannot insert duplicate key in object (table1), The duplicate key value is (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, oledb

I have a product entry page through we keep on adding product entries in our database.

Product location wise there are 2 series. e.g., `ABCTMP`(Series(1-max)) and `XYZ`(Series(1-max)).

Table is having primary key constraint which is a combination of 4 columns. Out of 4, only one is giving an issue while increment series combination wise.

That first column is location wise product code as stated above and it is of data type `char(20)` as it stores values like `ABCTMP01` and through classic asp code. We increment that last `01` value by addition of one into existing value.

Right now, facing issue when last value reaches `99` and turns to `100`. It generates code 100 through code but unable to insert in database and giving this error that was due to existing entry in database.

Duplicate key part is same one which I mentioned above in subject/header. If I delete record from table of record no. 100 to check, it gives me proper record of 99 through above query and through above classic asp code, it generates next code as 99+1 = 100.

But when I again try to add next series record for 101, even through SQL mgt studio, it gives me below error.

**Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'prdct_mst_tab'. The duplicate key value is (PWATERTMP100 , 006, Y, 01). The statement has been terminated.**

Have tried by dropping constraint and changing size of data type `char(20)` to `char(30)` as there are dependencies on table. But not worked. Then, have tried by changing data type from `char(30)` to `varchar(30)`, still not worked. Then again tried by manually

> executing insert command

in SQL itself, but same error occurred for 101th record.

Before generating next series, there is select statement to check latest inserted record which will get incremented later.

For generating next record of 101,there select statement must show last inserted record of 100, but it's still giving 99th record and code is generating as 100 again and the error continues the same. I do not understand why it's not taking 100th record when I execute SELECt statement in SQL mgt studio. DataType of that PWATERTMP100 column is char(20).

Below my classic asp code for series generation and SQL 'SELECT top 1 *' statement for record count for location wise product.

```
select top 1 * 
from prdct_mst_tab 
where pmt_prdct_cd like 'PWATER%' 
and pmt_umt_unit_cd='006' 
AND PMT_CMT_CMPNY_CD='01' 
order by pmt_prdct_cd desc
```

Classic ASP Code: -

```
If recordset.eof Then 
    getcode="ABCTMP01" 
Else
    getcode = clng(Mid(recordset("Column1"),10,20))
        response.write("Hello" & getcode)
    getcode = getcode +1
        response.write("<br />Hello" & getcode)
    getcode = "ABCTMP" & getcode
        response.write("<br />Hello" & getcode)
End if
```

Below for adding generated product code in database table.

Sql is as below

```
select * from Table1
recordset.open sql,con,3,2
recordset.addnew
recordset("Column1")=getcode
recordset.update 
recordset.close
```

> Note : Values given above are sample one.

I want the record gets inserted even when it turns from `99` to `100`, means code will become `ABCTMP99` - `ABCTMP100` and continue from `series` starting with `100` range(3 digits)like 100, 101, 102....

Comment: Is the error really _The duplicate key value is (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)_? Please edit your question and post the real error. Possibly 100 is being truncated to 00. Debugging the code would help. Generating unique keys in the application layer is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Real error is like this - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'table1'.

Comment: You means to say as data type is char(20), once value turns from 99 to 100, that value 100 gets converted to 00 due to char data type size.. right?

Comment: That's just a guess. Normally you'd get a truncation error from the database. The only way you'll find out is debug your program and confirm what it is actually trying to write to the database. Also try a _third_ time to post the error. The important bit is _The duplicate key value_ part because it gives you a clue about the data causing the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful for me if you could guide me on how to find out truncation error from database.My knowledge in database is not on expert level.Also, can you please elaborate what do you mean by post an error third time in this case?

Comment: So let me clarify - you tried the insert statement directly in Management Studio, and this insert statement contained the expected value `XYZ100` and you still got a PK violation error? You have posted an incomplete error twice, so now try a third time - please edit your question and post the actual error including the 'duplicate value' part that you get when you run your query in management studio. Also please post the query you ran in management studio. Right now there isn't enough info in your question to work out the issue.

Comment: Ok. Have again tried insert statement in managment studio and got below error.

Comment: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'prdct_mst_tab'. The duplicate key value is (PWATERTMP100        , 006, Y, 01).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: OK. Now you need to look at the existing data in that table and see if there is already a record with that key.

Comment: ok. record with PWATER100 is there in database, But when I try to check for record count through select statement before insert statement for lastly inserted record. it's giving me 1 record when execute in SQL mgt studio but when I try to print the same on front end through classic asp , it's giving me count as -1. I do not understand why it's not going to 101 post 100.

Comment: So firstly note that the description of your problem is now incorrect and this is due to insufficient analysis of the problem. i.e. you think it wasn't going from 99 to 100 but actually it's not going from 100 to 101. Secondly note that your problem description also excludes any code that describes how you find this record count.   Can you please update your question with these three bits of information: 1. The actual error (i,e, the "duplicate key" part; 2. The code that generates the problem. (the count part that you are talking about); 3. The true symptom (going from 100 to 101)

Comment: below one is the query checking record count for reference.

Comment: select top 1 * from prdct_mst_tab where pmt_prdct_cd like 'PWATER%' and pmt_umt_unit_cd='006' 
AND PMT_CMT_CMPNY_CD='01' order by pmt_prdct_cd desc

Comment: Duplicate key part is same one which I mentioned above. If I delete record from table of record no. 100 to check, it gives me proper record of 99 through above query and through above classic asp code, it generates next code as 99+1 = 100

Comment: And now for generating next record of 101, select statement must show last inserted record of 100, but it's still giving 99th record and code is generating as 100 again and the error continues the same. I do not understand why it's not taking 100th record. DataType of that PWATERTMP100 column is char(20)

Comment: Sorry - I see that you did put the code in there.

Comment: I will pose an answer but you have a large number of design issue that you should fix

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but I am also new to forum and to this issue. Have edited my post with some corrections now from whatever understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the order by in this:

```
select top 1 * from prdct_mst_tab 
where pmt_prdct_cd like 'PWATER%' 
and pmt_umt_unit_cd='006' 
AND PMT_CMT_CMPNY_CD='01' 
order by pmt_prdct_cd desc
```

Does not do what you expect.

Try running this in management studio:

```
select * from prdct_mst_tab 
where pmt_prdct_cd like 'PWATER%' 
and pmt_umt_unit_cd='006' 
AND PMT_CMT_CMPNY_CD='01' 
order by pmt_prdct_cd desc
```

You'll see that the `100` appears *before* `99` because it is ordering it alphanumerically not numerically.

In fact you will also see that `10` appears before `9` - how did you ever get past this?

You have a fundamental design flaw. I will *add* to that by posing a solution which cements the design flaw in place and introduces new bugs. But it will give you a result.

One *workaround* is to do something this:

```
select 
MAX(
  CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(RTRIM(pmt_prdct_cd),3)) = 1 
    THEN RIGHT(RTRIM(pmt_prdct_cd),3)
    ELSE '0' + RIGHT(RTRIM(pmt_prdct_cd),2)
  END
) As LargestNumber
from prdct_mst_tab 
where pmt_prdct_cd like 'PWATER%' 
and pmt_umt_unit_cd='006' 
AND PMT_CMT_CMPNY_CD='01'
```

What does this do?

It checks if the last three characters are a number. If it is it uses it.

If it isn't a number it grabs the last two characters and puts a zero in front.

Then it picks the largest number out of all of those.

note - this returns a number, it doesn't return the full product code. So you'll need to remove the ASP `Mid` code that tries to pull the number out.

This might work until you find some other data or case that you haven't mentioned yet. Like for example if there are trailing characters that aren't numeric. Or for when you need a four character number

**Make no mistake - you have a fundamental design flaw and this just prolongs the issue, adds complexity, and introduces more bugs down the track**

Some basic observations:

- char is a bad data type for this
- It has concurrency issues - if two requests call this at the same time (easily done from a web app), it returns the same number and they both try and insert a duplicate value
- You should not be assigning and storing incrementing numbers like this. Just use an `IDENTITY` in the database.

I guess since you are using classic ASP, you are not in a situation that you can redesign this.

You need to decide whether you are going to patch this with something that will introduce new bugs or fix it properly.

Does each product code *really* need to be incremented within it's own domain like that? Is there any issue with having ABC01 then DEF02 then XYZ03?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. Have tried running below SQL query.

Comment: select top 1 * from prdct_mst_tab where pmt_prdct_cd like 'PWATER%' and pmt_umt_unit_cd='006' 
AND PMT_CMT_CMPNY_CD='01' order by pmt_prdct_cd desc

Comment: It's giving me list of records starting with record 99 ..then 11, 100, 10..01 sequence like this..

Comment: Also, when I try to run your max query in SQL mt studio, got below error as 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TMP01         ' to data type int.'

Comment: My SQL version is ' Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (Intel X86) '

Comment: For earlier few records, it was PWATER and later on changed to PWATERTMP..This is one product type, other products are having another product series like 'RES01' etc..

Comment: The "Conversion Failed" error is what I was talking about in the answer when I said this solution will introduce more bugs. The problem is that you assumed there would only ever be two characters in the number. Now there are three. This is a fundamental design flaw. I will edit my question to provide something more robust but really you are just patching a design flaw and introducing more bugs.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I need to check for earlier records and their business wise impact before implementing the solution which you have suggested to fix it properly.

Comment: I have edited the answer. You need to communicate to stakeholders that your system has a design flaw that needs to be fixed, and this patch is just adding to risk of failure. I suspect there may be other data values that cause issues.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that but again it will throw an error when it reaches 1000 series and it's not a feasible solution to change the code every time as per bug. It's better to fix it instead of patching it.

Comment: One more thing on which I want your suggestion that If I decide to fix it properly with extra column with Idntity set on it and then by just adding PWATER with number series to calculate number code, what should be included in that primary key constraint along with rest 3 columns. ? i.e Newly added Extra Identity column or earlier product code column containing PWATER and number?

Comment: It's a tricky question. If you create an identity column on a table, you can create a PK just on that column because it's always unique. What was the original reasoning behind having a PK on those four columns? Normally that's to enforce some data integrity but you've already broken data integrity rules by putting an integer value in with a string value anyway. You can have a PK on the identity field _and_ in addition, put a unique constraint on another set of fields if you like, but what is the purpose? Do business users know or care about these four fields?